# Bootstrap tooltip need to be in single line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip

I have created a tooltip using bootstrap for dropdown control. It shows the tooltip.
But since this control is binded inside `class="col-sm-4"` tooltip text is broken to new lines. But I expect to show this in a single line. Any idea to make this?

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
                <select class="form-control" id="ddlSchoolAttended" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Some tooltip 2!Some tooltip 2!Some ">
          <option value="08">08 -Year 8 or below</option>
    <option value="09">09 -Year 9 or equivalent</option>
    <option value="10">10 -Completed Year 10</option>
    <option value="11">11 -Completed Year 11</option>
    <option value="12">12 -Completed Year 12</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="">--Not Specified--</option>
          </select><br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
.tooltip-inner {
  white-space:nowrap;
  max-width:none;
}
```

Add this to your CSS after the Bootstrap CSS. However, using the hover on a right, even right auto, will be off screen on smaller viewports, but since smaller viewports are generally touch, hovers may make this require a double tap to work. I usually use a script to detect touch for IOS, Android, and Windows mobile and then only use the tooltip on no-touch devices, so this doesn't interfere with user taps.

Answer (score 11):

Although Christina's answer works, it only patches the problem and may create other problems elswhere. In the bootstrap documentation it is mentioned this:

> Tooltips in button groups, input groups, and tables require special setting
>   When using tooltips on elements within a .btn-group or an .input-group, or on table-related elements, you'll have to specify the option `container: 'body'` to avoid unwanted side effects (such as the element growing wider and/or losing its rounded corners when the tooltip is triggered).
>
> see [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

so all you need to do is add `container: 'body'` like so:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({container: 'body'})}
);
```

hope this helps